# How to add texture to an OBJ?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am currently working with the Intel RealSense D455 scanner with the PCL library and more precisely with the Fast Organized Mesh method to generate a mesh in OBJ format.

I can get a mesh of the scene I'm scanning but I can't find the texture, is there a way to add it?

Thanks.

My code :

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
cloud->resize(size);
cloud-> Height = 480;
cloud-> Width = 848;


for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cloud->at(i).x = Cloud[i].x;
    cloud->at(i).y = Cloud[i].y;
    cloud->at(i).z = Cloud[i].z;

}

std::cout << "Fast mesh started " << "\n";
pcl::OrganizedFastMesh<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr orgMesh(new pcl::OrganizedFastMesh<pcl::PointXYZ());
pcl::PolygonMesh triangles;
orgMesh->setTriangulationType(pcl::OrganizedFastMesh<pcl::PointXYZ>::TRIANGLE_RIGHT_CUT);
orgMesh->setInputCloud(cloud);
orgMesh->reconstruct(triangles);
std::cout << "start saving the fast mesh obj..." << "\n";
pcl::io::saveOBJFile("Mesh.obj", triangles);
```

Comment: Where do you expect the texture to come from, if your points just have XYZ?

Comment: I already tried with the XYZRGB points but the fonction setInputCloud( ) only takes a XYZ points.. also tried to create two types of point cloud one XYZ and the other XYZRGB then use the copyPointCloud function but nothing changed too still no texture. Do you have any idea about the reason ? Thanks

Comment: Then I guess orgMesh is only capable of generating non-textured meshes. It would need RGB to generate a texture. Maybe there is some other algorithm that is able to apply a point cloud texture onto a mesh.

Comment: You could try pcl::OrganizedFastMesh<pcl::PointXYZRGB>, but that would still ignore the RGB data for each point even though it would let you pass XYZRGB points.

Comment: Wavefront .obj stores UV texture binding, but the texture sampler information it self. Just like materials are stored in a separate file  Material template library .mlt. RTFM - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file

Comment: The PolygonMesh tells you which points belong to each triangle. You could generate a texture based on the 3 points that are the corners of each triangle

Comment: I created an objet called polygonMesh in order to generate an OBJ with a texture but didn't found how I can reconstruct it since the reconstruct function only takes PolygonMesh as a parameter + I think I have to fill it in with the data from the cloud ? anyone have an idea on how to do it ?